# Replace an empty line and a line below it with <tag> using sed

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I have something like this;

```
One blank line below

> This is a text
> This is another line of text

One blank line above
```

Trying to get something like this;

```
One blank line below

<blockquote>
> This is a text
> This is another line of text
</blockquote>

One blank line above
```

Tried this;

```bsh
sed 's/^\n\(>\)/\r<blockquote>\r\1/g' test.txt

and

sed 's/^\(>.*\)\n$/\1\r<\/blockquote>\r/g' test.txt
```

These regexes worked fine for me while I was in vim (8.1), however, while trying it out from my shell(bash), I saw no results. Nothing seemed to have changed while I ran these from the shell. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: What OS are you on? There appears to be some \n to \r conversions.  Can you post the output of `sed -n l test.txt`

Comment: The sed model is different. It processes a line at a time, unless some special incantations are invoked, which is not the case here. So the regexes would never match and so output=input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `awk` for this with a state machine. I use the flags `blank` and `block` to indicate a blank line and a block

```
awk '
    /^$/ { blank++ }                                            # Blank line
    blank && /^>/ { blank=0; block++; print "<blockquote>" }    # First ">" line after blank
    block && blank { block=0; print "</blockquote>" }           # First blank after ">"
    /^./ { blank=0 }                                            # Non-blank line
    { print }                                                   # Print the input data
'
```

Test data

```
One blank line below

> This is a text
> This is another line of text

One blank line above

------------------------------------

One blank line below
> This is a text
> This is another line of text
One blank line above

------------------------------------

One blank line below

> This is a text

> This is another line of text

One blank line above
```

Output

```
One blank line below

<blockquote>
> This is a text
> This is another line of text
</blockquote>

One blank line above

------------------------------------

One blank line below
> This is a text
> This is another line of text
One blank line above

------------------------------------

One blank line below

<blockquote>
> This is a text
</blockquote>

<blockquote>
> This is another line of text
</blockquote>

One blank line above
```

Comment: That works. I was rooting for a `sed` based answer and came across this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed Apparenlty newlines parsing seems a bit more complex than it is.Awk seems reasonable to use I guess (: Have to dig into more on awk regexes ^_^

Comment: `awk` regex are much the same as any other regex